# How to install a .zip package via requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

I've got URL similar to`https://github.com/me/my-project/archive/master.zip`

During development, I was able to install it with:

`pip install https://github.com/me/my-project/archive/master.zip`

How would I go about adding that to requirements.txt? I can only see options for repositories.

Thanks.

Comment: You call look into this too [python packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [in the current version](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#example) you just need to bring in the path to the zip package directly:

```
# requirements.txt
https://github.com/me/my-project/archive/master.zip
```

Then... it's done. No need to specify any additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to add a VCS source without using a link to the .zip file. This needs to be added to requirements.txt:

`-e git+https://github.com/me/my-project/#egg=my-project`

Comment: Wow! This absolutely does not answer the question about installing from a zip file. It just shows that the question was an XY problem.

Comment: You are totally correct, @zvone. I've changed the accepted answer to match the title.

Answer (score 2):

Without third-party dependencies out of the box, you can do this by simply adding the following line to `requirements.txt`:

```
my-project @ https://github.com/me/my-project/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me only because the package I am using needs to be installed directly from a zip that's been downloaded from github.

But, this worked for me:

```
from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install', 'package-downloaded-from-github-master.zip'])
```

Which I got from here:  [How can I install a github zip file with pip and setup.py from requirements.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003470/how-can-i-install-a-github-zip-file-with-pip-and-setup-py-from-requirements-txt)