# How can I install a github zip file with pip and setup.py from requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

I am working with a library called `lief` which due to it lacking full python 3.7 support from pip, I need to install it from the following link `https://github.com/lief-project/packages/raw/lief-master-latest/pylief-0.9.0.dev.zip`.

The issue I am having is that it works fine when i do `pip install https://github.com/lief-project/packages/raw/lief-master-latest/pylief-0.9.0.dev.zip`, it works fine, but if i put that link in my requirements.txt file, it fails to install in travis with the error

```
error in rapido setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'://githu'"
```

Most of the examples I have seen about requirements.txt and github link points to a commit hash. How can I install a github zip file from requirements.txt so when i run `pip install .`, I am not getting the above mentioned error?

I should add that if i do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it works fine, but if i do `pip install -e .` which uses setup.py, it will fail

Comment: Can u try like this in req. txt file . 

`git+https://github.com/lief-project/packages/raw/lief-master-latest/pylief-0.9.0.dev.zip`

Comment: No, that only works if i do `-r requirements.txt`. That is not the question being asked here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

Comment: Edit your question to show what you actually have: your `setup.py`, your `requirements.txt`, and anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: @FlyingTeller not a duplicate because those are asking about `.git` links, or release tags, not a zip file.

Answer (score 2):

As a stop gap measure, I am doing the following in my `setup.py` for anyone that runs into a similar problem. This works with `pip install .`

```py
from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install', 'https://github.com/lief-project/packages/raw/lief-master-latest/pylief-0.9.0.dev.zip'])
```

But would really like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this using `pip install .` where the link is in `requirements.txt`.